# replaced link is not calling using ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am putting liking and unliking link for games.
   Initially like is active where user click on like it will show

```
 unlike link 
 1 like this game
```

that is ok.
But when we click on unlike link it reload the page.
I dont want to reload the page

```
<div class="gameLikeStatus">
 <a href="likeit" id="likeitlink">Like</a>
</div>
<div class="totalLikes">
<span id="likesCount"><s:property value="likes"/></span> like this game<br>
</div>
<script>

$('a#likeitlink').bind('click',function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $('.gameLikeStatus').html('<a href="unlikeit" id="Unlikeitlink">Unlike</a>');
    $likesNo= $('#likesCount').html();
    $likesNo++;
    $('#likesCount').html(""+$likesNo);

}); 

$('a#Unlikeitlink').bind('click',function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $('.gameLikeStatus').html('<a href="likeit" id="likeitlink">Like</a>');
    $likesNo= $('#likesCount').html();
    $likesNo--;
    $('#likesCount').html(""+$likesNo);
}); 

</script>
```

Comment: I guess you need to use live() function of jquery to add handlers to new dom elements you add: http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: @Juanillo live is now deprecated. You should use [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead.

Comment: @dystroy yeah you're right, I'm used to an old version of jQuery, cause I'm lately working with it and we can't upgrade.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace

```
$('a#Unlikeitlink').bind('click',function(event){
```

with

```
$('.gameLikeStatus').on('click', '#Unlikeitlink', function(event){
```

(and the same for the other one)

When you're executing `$('a#Unlikeitlink').bind`, the collection is empty as the link doesn't exist yet, so this does nothing. [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) enables the delegation to objects not yet existing. As you didn't bind the callback, you weren't preventing the normal link behavior, hence your problem.

You should also parse the html that your increment or decrement :

```
$('.gameLikeStatus').on('click', '#likeitlink', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $('.gameLikeStatus').html('<a href="unlikeit" id="Unlikeitlink">Unlike</a>');
    $likesNo= parseInt($('#likesCount').html(), 10) || 0;
    $likesNo++;
    $('#likesCount').html(""+$likesNo);
}); 

$('.gameLikeStatus').on('click', '#Unlikeitlink', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $('.gameLikeStatus').html('<a href="likeit" id="likeitlink">Like</a>');
    $likesNo= parseInt($('#likesCount').html(), 10) || 0;
    $likesNo--;
    $('#likesCount').html(""+$likesNo);
});
```

(you could also more simply keep it in a global var instead of reading it each time)

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/XcXhj/)

Comment: It is not calling the function

Comment: I have seen your link. It is performing great.Thanks...  But it is not working on my system

Comment: Thanks for your great code snippet. Its perfect. Problem was I was using version 1.5.

Comment: OK. Thanks to you for the update, I was really wondering what could have gone wrong for you :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're using an older jQuery version. In jQuery versions before 1.7 you have to add the event listener differently as in 1.7. Use .live instead of .on.

Example:

```
$('.gameLikeStatus').live('click', function(event){
    // Your code here
});
```